# Remove ambiguity between hyperjaxb generated classes and apache cxf generated clases

Tags: spring, web-services, jaxb, cxf, hyperjaxb

I have the following project structure:

service-parent

|__service-schemas

|__service-database

|__service-contract

|__service-implementation

I am using hyperjaxb3 because I ultimately need that the objects passed through the web service are the ones that will be finally stored in the database (no transformations required).

In the module **service-schemas** I have defined the XSD schemas I will be using in my web service. **service-database** will generate JPA-JAXB objects through hyperjaxb3 use. **service-contract** will generate java service interfaces by using cxf-codegen-plugin maven plugin. **service-implementation** will be the final web service implementation. I think the idea is OK. However the problem rises when I use hyperjaxb3 and cxf-codegen-plugin, because I need JPA classes (the ones I generate using hyperjaxb3) to extend a **BaseCustomClass**. The problem is that when I create my test to, say, the web service method **persitCustom(CustomType)**, the XML is being deserialized to **CustomType** as generated by cxf-codegen-plugin (which is the tool I used to generate service interfaces). Now, that class is not exactly the **CustomType** generated by hyperjaxb3 (even though it is not a problem at compile time, cause both classes are "almost" the same, same properties, same package, etc...) The question is how do I force my service implementation to use hyperjaxb3 generated classes instead of *cxf-codegen-plugin* generated ones.

These are the versions I am using

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-hyperjaxb3-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <extension>true</extension>
            <args>
                <arg>-Xinheritance</arg>
            </args>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

This is for cxf-codegen-plugin

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.9</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>
                                    ${project.build.directory}/src/main/resources/SharedModel/sampleWeb/service.wsdl
                                </wsdl>
                                <wsdlLocation>classpath*:sampleWeb/service.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                                <bindingFiles/>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: What maven version of hyperjaxb3 , cxf-codegen-plugin are you using , please add those details

Comment: I added the versions

Comment: Short answer: use the HJ3 generated JAR as episode. I'll post the full answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figure out a way by telling cxf-codegen-plugin to exclude classes in the namespace that contained the conflicting types. I added this lines to the configuration section of the plugin. They where under **http://conflicting/types/namespace/** namespace

```
<extraargs>
    <extraarg>-nexclude</extraarg>
    <extraarg>http://conflicting/types/namespace/</extraarg>
</extraargs>
```